# Pass values from first page to third page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am making a project. In that project first page is Login page.
In Login page, user'll enter user Id and Password, if match, page will redirect to second page.
In second page there is a hyperlink to go to third page.
In third page I want to show user's all the details like- firstName, lastName, emailId, mobileNumber, password etc. 
My doubt is how to carry userId and Password from first page to third Page. 
Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your username is unique, you can carry the username via querystring to your pages and display details according to it

Comment: Best place is to create a custom Principle and store your user data(no passwords) in the principle. The Current Principle is accessible anywhere in the `HttpContext.Current`. In this you dont have to worry on which page you land cause the User data is always available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the user name and ID not the password, you don't need to save the password because it's not a good for security.

Go through this, it'll help you.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WindowsPrincipal class to save the user credential it's save the user name and ID not the password, you don't need to save the password because it's not a good for security.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies or session , will help you for both authentication and for what u mentioned here

http://www.w3schools.com/ASp/asp_cookies.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 0):

You can store userId in Session or cookie on login success and get it on required page.
Do not store password in session or cookie as it may harmful from security point of view.
I suggest you to refer asp.net state management.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management

Answer (score 0):

The way you are redirecting to Second Page from Login Page, just redirect directly from Login to Third Page.

Also, while checking login details, if user is an authenticated one, keep `User ID` in Session, so that you can easily retrieve logged in user's all details using that `User ID`.

Answer (score 0):

In your login page check username and password is valid or not

if valid then create a session of userid for e.g `Session["userid"]=userid`

now in your third page you can get users firstname,lastname etc from userid

E.g:

```
int userid =Convert.ToInt(Session["userid"]);
var userDetails = GetUserInfomationfromid (userid) // here you can get user infomation from userid
```

if you want to read more about StateManagement in ASP.net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction